# How to get custom parameter in response in payumoney payment gateway php integration

Tags: php, payment-gateway, payumoney

I am working on payumoney payment gateway with php integration. Now I have almost done, but just want the custom parameter in the response after success or failure when I am return from the payumoney website payment process.

So if anybody have idea regarding then it will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Show us some code? Post some logs.

Answer (score 3):

You can use udf1 to udf5 user defined parameters to pass your custom parameter
for a example,

```
<input type="hidden" name="udf1" value="<?php echo $custom_var1; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="udf2" value="<?php echo $custom_var2; ?>" />
```

Than in your success page you could get this passed parameters data,

```
<?php
...
$custom_var1 = $_POST["udf1"];
$custom_var2 = $_POST["udf2"];
...
?>
```